# How to use select function and with function together in laravel

Tags: php, laravel-5

I want to select some column from the main table with laravel `with` function but when I use `select` it gives null in with for example

```
table1::select('column1','column2')->with(['table2'])->paginate($request->query('per_page', 10));
```

If I use select then it gives `null` in `table2` but if I remove the select then it gives values in `table2`.

Can anyone please let me know what I am doing wrong or what can be done here

Answer (score 0):

$subskills_users = Subskills::select('id','subskills_title')->with(['User'])->paginate(15);

I used the above in my local db. And it works fine.

Do you have made the relation in your user table? I have made it in my Subskills model like this:

```
public function User()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\User', 'users_subskills', 'subskill_id', 
   'user_id');
}
```

Comment: for with table I have used morphTo